# Replacing occurrences of String Array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

This is my array

```
["<h2>Some text, and some info.</h2>", "<h2>Another text</h2>"]
```

I need to make it look like this

```
<h2>Some text, and some info.</h2><h2>Another text</h2>
```

I need to remove `["` `", "` `"]`

Tried an `extension` to call `replcaingOccurances` on an array of `[String]`

```
extension Array where Element == String {
    
   func replacingOccurrences(of target: String, with replacement: String, options: NSString.CompareOptions) -> Self
     {
            return self.map( { $0.replacingOccurrences(of: target, with: replacement, options: options) } )
        }
    }
```

Background: I'm saving `html` data in an `array` in `Core Data`

Trying to use the extension does not filter any occurances

```
let result = ResultCoreDataManager.sharedInstance.getResults()
let filtered = result?.replacingOccurrences(of: "<[\"\"]\",\"\", \"", with: "", options: .regularExpression)
```

Help please?

Comment: I think you might be making a wrong assumption. If I remember correctly, CoreData supports saving arrays as a data type. If you want to preserve your info as an array, just add an array to your model. The fact that your array is printed enclosed in square brackets and with commas between the elements is just a side-effect of the way print works. (As I recall it calls the method `description()` on the items you pass to it. For arrays, that returns a string beginning and ending with square brackets and including a comma-separated list of the array elements' descriptions.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a string array with 2 elements, so why not just use `joined`?

```swift
let htmls = ["<h2>Some text, and some info.</h2>", "<h2>Another text</h2>"]
let output = htmls.joined()
print(output)
//<h2>Some text, and some info.</h2><h2>Another text</h2>
```